# Find and Replace Specific characters in a variable with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, capturing-group

Problem: I have a variable with characters I'd like to prepend another character to within the same string stored in a variable

Ex. "[blahblahblah]" ---> "\[blahblahblah\]"

Current Solution: Currently I accomplish what I want with two steps, each step attacking one bracket

Ex.

```
temp=[blahblahblah]
firstEscaped=$(echo $temp | sed s#'\['#'\\['#g)
fullyEscaped=$(echo $firstEscaped | sed s#'\]'#'\\]'#g)
```

This gives me the result I want but I feel like I can accomplish this in one line using [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). I've just had no luck and I'm getting burnt out. Most examples I come across involve wanting to extract the text between brackets instead of what I'm trying to do. [This](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99320) is my latest attempt to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways, (only 1 `s/s/r/` with a fancier reg-ex), but this works, given your sample input

```
fully=$(echo "$temp" | sed 's/\([[]\)/\\\1/;s/\([]]\)/\\\1/') ; echo "$fully"
```

**output**

```
\[blahblahblah\]
```

Note that it is quite OK to chain together multiple `sed` operations, separated by `;` OR if in a `sed` script file, by blank lines.

Read about `sed` capture-groups using `\(...\)` pairs, and referencing them by number, i.e. `\1`.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

```
$ temp=[blahblahblah]    
$ fully=$(echo "$temp" |sed 's/\[\|\]/\\&/g'); echo "$fully"
\[blahblahblah\]
```

Brief explanation,

- `\[\|\]`: target to substitute '[' or ']', and for '[', ']', and '|' need to be escaped.
- `&`: the character `&` to refer to the pattern which matched, and mind that it also needs to be escaped.

As @Gordon Davisson's suggestion, you may also use bracket expression to avoid the extended format regex,

```
sed 's/[][]/\\&/g'
```

Comment: You need to double-quote `$temp` to prevent word splitting and wildcard expansion. Note that `[ ]` is a shell wildcard, so it might get expanded unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is copied from the OP, and will modify this.

Comment: I also just noticed that the regular expression you're using is in extended format (using `|` to separate alternatives). That generally won't work unless you use `sed -r` (GNU sed) or `sed -E` (BSD sed). It'd probably be better to use a bracket expression (although a bracket expression containing brackets is ... tricky). `sed 's/[][]/\\&/g'` should work.

Comment: Very good point. @GordonDavisson I would add your suggestion to my answer as complementary.

Comment: I tried `s/[][]/\\&/g` in my funky environment, and it didn't work. That's why I went with 2 passes, but glad to know that `[][]` can work. Good luck to all.